# ASP validation control on same form but different divs

Tags: html, asp.net, validation, vbscript, webforms

I have one html form, inside it, I am calling 3 divs from 3 different aspx forms. On 3 different divs, I have different controls, like address details of customer in one div, contact details in other div etc and I have 3 submit buttons on each div to submit customers info. Now, my question is, I want to validate some text boxes on each div, for validations I am using asp:RequiredFieldValidator. But problem occurs when I am trying to submit blank field from one div, it validating the controls from other divs also, and therefore I am unable to submit info from only one div. So how to separate the validation for different divs on same html form.
I hope you will get my question and response as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example

```
    <asp:textbox id="tb1" runat=Server />
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="ReqField1" controltovalidate="tb1"
validationgroup="valGroup1" errormessage="Required" runat=Server />

<asp:ImageButton id="Button2" causesvalidation=true
validationgroup="valGroup2" ImageUrl="img.gif" runat=Server />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) . It worked for me. Unable to vote your answer. But thanks from heart.

Comment: Your welcome. You can select as accepted answer.